# SUM Columns Sequentially When You Only Have Date(Without time part)

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say you have an invoice table:

```
ID | Amount | Date
========================
1  | 50     | 2017-12-08
2  | 100    | 2017-12-11
3  | 150    | 2017-12-11
4  | 250    | 2017-12-12
```

I want to sum invoice ID: `2`, Date: `2017-12-11` and the rest of it. So all invoice before `2017-12-11` would be included.

In this case would be SUM Invoice ID = 2 and 1(without ID=3)

---

Invoice table may filled like this too:

```
ID | Amount | Date
========================
1  | 50     | 2017-12-08
2  | 100    | 2017-12-11
3  | 150    | 2017-12-11
4  | 200    | 2017-12-09
5  | 250    | 2017-12-12
```

Look at Invoice ID: `4`. It has date that input backward. So Date column may not ordered.

The question is same. I want to sum invoice ID: `2`, Date: `2017-12-11` and the rest of it. So all invoice before `2017-12-11` would be included.

In this case would be SUM Invoice ID = 2, 4, 1(without ID=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your examples you can do:

```
select sum(amount)
from invoices i join
     invoices i2
     on i2.id = 2 and
        (i.date < i2.date or
         i.date = i2.date and i.id <= i2.id
        );
```

I'm not sure if this a general solution, given the lack of ordering on the ids.  But it should work for the data you have provided.